# SerialPort.DataReceived not firing

Tags: c#, port

so I have a hardware connected to a COM port, but when I try to get its input it doesnt receive nothing. It just doesnt fires that receives something.

First I get all the COM ports and I know that its connected to COM5 so I do

```
public void StartCOM(string COMPort, ref SerialPort serialPort)
{
    serialPort = new SerialPort(COMPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
    Debug.Log("Serial port inicializado en: " + COMPort + " |Baudrate: " + baudRate);
}
```

then I call

`serialPort.DataReceived += DebugReceivedData;`

That does:

```
void DebugReceivedData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log("Data recibida");
    SerialPort serialPortSender = (SerialPort)sender;
    string dataReceived = serialPortSender.ReadExisting();

    Debug.Log(dataReceived);
}
```

and finally I call:

```
public void OpenCOM(ref SerialPort serialPort)
{
    //Comprobamos si el serial port existe
    if (serialPort != null)
    {
        //Si ya está abierto no hacemos nada
        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            Debug.Log("El puerto " + serialPort.PortName + " ya estaba abierto");
        }
        //Si está cerrado lo abrimos
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Abrimos puerto: " + serialPort.PortName);
            serialPort.Open();

            // Set the read/write timeouts
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 16;
            //serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            //serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        }
    }
}
```

It wont never Debug "Data recibida".

Im using Unity with API 4.0

UPDATE:

Checking every frame (That does Update method)

```
private void Update()
{
    string dataReceived = serialPort.ReadExisting();
    Debug.Log(dataReceived);
}
```

It prints the received data (ie: -17F)

Comment: Does the device send anything? If not, you won't receive any events. Just because you opened the port doesn't mean the *device* is going to send anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos check the update. It receives data

Comment: You need to make sure the `SerialPort` configuration is what the device actually expects. This should be part of the documentation of the device; the general principles are outlined here: https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/rs-232-flow-control. Serial ports aren't plug and play.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, but I can get the data if I check every frame. But it doesnt trigger the event. It works but not with the event

Comment: That doesn't mean your configuration is correct. You're underestimating how low-level serial ports are :) Most of the time, wrong configuration doesn't break everything. Make sure the device is communicating properly, and that your configuration is correct; the event will fire correctly then.

Comment: @Luaan Okay thank you, I will keep trying :)

Comment: What kind of device are you trying to interface with? Doesn't it have documentation and/or configuration?

Comment: @Luaan I was using a NewTek-RS-8 for testing, but what I really want to do is control a camera with that (VC520) or just get its parameters like zoom ammount etc

Comment: Well, if you don't have the programming manual for the RS-8, your only option is to keep trying different configuration. `DtrEnable` might be needed, for example; different handshake protocols aren't compatible either.

Comment: @Luaan Ill test different options then (I dont have the manual since is an old hardware)